# Start a PyFladesk application got a ucrtbase.dll error on windows 10

Tags: python, flask, pyinstaller

I clone [PyFladesk repository](https://github.com/smoqadam/PyFladesk). Then create an application for the example application by the command

```
pyinstaller -w -F --add-data "templates;templates" --add-data "static;static" app.py
```

It's OK. After I run the application with the command `dist\app.exe`. This app is automatically closed when it is opened.

The error message show in the event log.

> Error module name:  ucrtbase.dll，version: 10.0.16299.125 Exception
> code:0xc0000409 Error applicaiton path:D:\pyfladesk_test\dist\app.exe

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you use python 3.7? pyinstaller doesn't work with this python version yet. Try python 3.6.

Comment: No, I use python 3.6.5.

Comment: Then it is not the same problem that I encountered.